# A way to check if browser supports otf

Tags: javascript, browser, font-face, modernizr

Is there a way to check if a browser supports otf (font) or not? I have modernizr but that only checks if the browser supports @font-face or not?

Comment: Usually people just use conversion services to create different representations of the same font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have the support for fonts in browsers: https://web.archive.org/web/20120319005254/http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=@font-face_browser_support
You should make your code check for the browser and then you will now if the font type is supported.

Comment: @aijimix Yeah, maybe thats the way to go. Or convert the font to different formats.